# use native base button with props

Tags: reactjs, react-native, native-base

i want to create a reusable button component but i am having some issues. I get back `undefined is not an onject evaluting '_nativebase.stylrsheetcreate'`. I tried destructing the onPress and title but no luck. Can someone give a clear explanation on how to resolve this? thanks

```
import React from 'react';
import {  View, Text, Button, StyleSheet } from 'native-base';

export const StyledButton = props => {
    return (
        <View style={styles.button}>
            <Button
                block
                full
                bordered
                light
                onPress={this.props.onPress}
            >
                <Text
                    style={{
                        color: '#FFFFFF',
                    }}
                >
                    {this.props.title}
                </Text>
                {this.props.children}
            </Button>
        </View>
    );
};


const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    button: {
        flex: 1,
        padding: 10,
    }
});
```

to Render

```
<StyledButton
title='Cancel'
onPress={this.somefunction}

/>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove `this` use `props.someprop`

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import { View, Text, Button } from 'native-base';

export const StyledButton = props => {
  return (
    <View style={styles.button}>
      <Button block full bordered light onPress={props.onPress}>
        <Text
          style={{
            color: '#FFFFFF',
          }}>
          {props.title}
        </Text>
        {props.children}
      </Button>
    </View>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  button: {
    flex: 1,
    padding: 10,
  }
});
```

Comment: looks like native base doesn't provide `StyleSheet` https://docs.nativebase.io/Customize.html#custom-component-headref

Comment: how do i pass onpress to the component?  i want to do something like this onPress={() => {this.props.navigation.navigate('somepage');}}. it doesnt work when i do that

Comment: i am not using this.somefuction. is it not possible to use a navigation props like onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('somescreen')} ?

Comment: you'll need to pass the navigation as prop, and inside your on press do `prop.navigation.navigate('Screen')`

Comment: ok heres a better question, it is possible for onpress to have both a navigation prop and regular onpress prop at the same time?